# is it possible to run gradle in live mode

Tags: gradle

In sbt there is a live mode, if I use sbt ~run, then every time a java source changed, it will reload automatically. playframework also support that so that when change a source code, we don't reload manually. For gradle, I am running spring boot, but need to shutdown it and then startup after change some code, even if I am using --daemon, it still need some manually work. Anyway to load the code automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A live mode for Gradle is in the works but not currently available. Plugins such as spring-boot may of course provide their own solution.